# Setting conditionals in webpack config

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have seen examples that show instead of assigning an object to `module.exports` in `webpack.config.js` they assign a function that returns the config object and takes a parameter for the build mode (thus allowing conditional build logic).

However, when I try this myself the build mode parameter is undefined.

eg:

```js
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {

    console.log(webpackEnv); //undefined
    return { 
               //... webpack config 
            }
}
```

Is there an additional step required to inject the build mode or have I done something wrong?

Comment: how are you passing `mode` to your webpack, via command line script? If so how does that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to pass in mode as an argument via command line or via your script tag then you are looking for second parameter in your function which has passed in argument value from your script execution.

Assuming your script tag is `webpack --mode=development`

Your function would look like:

```
module.exports = function(webpackEnv, argv) {

  console.log(webpackEnv); //undefined
  console.log('arguments', argv);
  return {
    mode: argv.mode === 'development' ? 'development' : 'production',
    //... webpack config 
  }
}
```

For reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

Answer (score 0):

I use webpack-merge to import the remote config.

Also include `--config` when you run the webpack cmd.

In the `package.json`:

```
webpack --watch --config config/webpack/webpack.<name of your file>.js
```

file: `webpack.config.json`

```
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const common = require("./webpack.common");

module.exports = (env) => {
  return merge(common(env), {
    mode: "development",
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: "node_modules/**/*",
    },
    // bunch of other stuff...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script that runs something like:

```
webpack --env=stage
```

You can then pass the "stage" value to webpack.config.js as such:

```
module.exports = (env) => {
  const someVariable = env; // 'env' equates to "stage"
  return {
    your_webpack_config
  }
};
```